# Automatically post to Google+ on new post

Tags: google

Is there a way to automatically post to Google+ whenever there is a blog post on WordPress?

I found very conflicting information if that is possible or not. Ideally this should be free of course.

Comment: Are you searching for a plugin or do you want to code it?

Comment: @kaiser Well I am not sure if it is possible in the first place. If there is a ready-made solution, this would be better. Depending on the effort required, I would be able to write it myself, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not currently have a public API to allow posting to G+ from anywhere other than their web interface. The scripts that currently do so are using the "mobile" interface to do so, and as such are fragile at best. Additionally, they don't work with 2-step verification (which you should enable on your Google account for security reasons).

Therefore at this time, there is no safe way to automate posting to Google+.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine (John Eckman) wrote [WPGPlus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgplus/) which sets out with the goal to do just that. I know some people have had success with it, others not so much. However, it may be a good place to look at the code and use it as a starting point.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jetpack’s publicize module](https://jetpack.com/support/publicize/) to accomplish this.